# Haskell Servant (Client) - GET Request with headers

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm trying to replicate this curl request with Haskell Servant

```
curl -v -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
-H 'Client-ID: someapikey' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/clips/top?game=Overwatch&period=week&trending=false&limit=3'
```

Using Twitch API. Docs [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/clips/#get-top-clips)

This is what I've got so far

```
type Game = Text                                                                                                             

type Cursor = Text                                                                                                           

type Language = Text                                                                                                         

type Limit = Int                                                                                                             

type Period = Text                                                                                                           

type Trending = Bool                                                                                                         

type Application = Text                                                                                                      

type ClientID = Text                                                                                                         

type SearchClips = "kraken"                                                                                                  
                 :> "clips"                                                                                                  
                 :> "top"                                                                                                    
                 :> QueryParam "game" Game                                                                                   
                 :> QueryParam "cursor" Cursor                                                                               
                 :> QueryParam "language" Language                                                                           
                 :> QueryParam "limit" Limit                                                                                 
                 :> QueryParam "period" Period                                                                               
                 :> QueryParam "trending" Trending                                                                           
                 :> Header "Accept" Application                                                                              
                 :> Header "Client-ID" ClientID                                                                              
                 :> Get '[JSON] Search   

searchClipAPI :: Proxy SearchClips                                                                                           
searchClipAPI = Proxy                                                                                                        

search                                                                                                                       
  :: Maybe Game                                                                                                              
     -> Maybe Cursor                                                                                                         
     -> Maybe Language                                                                                                       
     -> Maybe Limit                                                                                                          
     -> Maybe Period                                                                                                         
     -> Maybe Trending                                                                                                       
     -> Maybe Application                                                                                                    
     -> Maybe ClientID                                                                                                       
     -> ClientM Search                                                                                                       
search = client searchClipAPI                                                                                                

baseURL :: BaseUrl                                                                                                           
baseURL = BaseUrl Https "api.twitch.tv" 443 ""
```

And this is how I 'run' it with http-tls

```
runGameClipsSearchClient :: Maybe Text -> IO ()                                                                              
runGameClipsSearchClient game = do                                                                                           

  mn <- NT.newTlsManager                                                                                                     

  let args = search                                                                                                          
             game                                                                                                            
             (Just "")                                                                                                       
             (Just "en")                                                                                                     
             (Just 50)                                                                                                       
             (Just "day")                                                                                                    
             (Just False)                                                                                                    
             (Just "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json")                                                                       
             (Just "someapikey")                                                                         

      envClient = mkClientEnv mn baseURL                                                                                     

  pPrint =<< runClientM args envClient
```

But I must be doing something wrong because I get a '404: not found' error with the haskell code but not with the curl request.

I suspect there's something wrong with my headers because when I remove the

```
'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'
```

from the curl request, I get the exact same response.

Comment: I've used `servant-client` multiple times and it worked, but I can't see what's wrong with your query... Looks completely fine to me, should work. If you won't get your answer here, I recommend creating an issue in the `haskell-servant` repository and ask there.

Comment: What does Wireshark show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `servant-client` has special handling of the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers -- if you try to include them using the `:> Header ...` mechanism, they are stripped out of the request in the function `requestToClientRequest` in `Servant.Client.Internal.HttpClient`.

I think the easiest way to force an `Accept` header is to add a request mangling function to your `Manager`.  This is definitely an ugly hack, but it seems to work.  (I don't have a Twitch client ID to test, but with this fix, I get a 400 instead of a 404 error, which I believe is progress.)

```
mn <- NT.newTlsManagerWith (NT.tlsManagerSettings { managerModifyRequest = fixAccept })
...
where fixAccept req
    = return $ req { requestHeaders = ("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json") :
                     filter (("Accept" /=) . fst) (requestHeaders req) }
```

Comment: That works! Getting the expected response from Twitch API.